# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Hello i'm experiencing this error when trying to build my EntityManager with Hibernate.

```
...INFO  | 2016-07-28 14:55:20 | [main] internal.PooledConnections (PooledConnections.java:39) - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
INFO  | 2016-07-28 14:55:20 | [main] dialect.Dialect (Dialect.java:153) - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
INFO  | 2016-07-28 14:55:20 | [main] internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl (LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:124) - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO  | 2016-07-28 14:55:20 | [main] type.BasicTypeRegistry (BasicTypeRegistry.java:148) - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@550a1967
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: entityManager] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:961)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:891)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)...
```

My persistence xml is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="entityManager">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>resultstorage.BenchmarkResult</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="12345"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <property name="connection_pool_size" value="1"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The annotated class im mapping is:
    package resultstorage;

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.BasicType;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BenchmarkResults")
public class BenchmarkResult {
private long id;
private String usecase;
private Date time;
private String server;
private long result;

public BenchmarkResult(String usecase, Date time, String server, long result) {
    this.usecase = usecase;
    this.time = time;
    this.server = server;
    this.result = result;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "USECASE")
public String getUsecase() {
    return usecase;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "TIME")
public Date getTime() {
    return time;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOSTNAME")
public String getServer() {
    return server;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "RESULT")
public long getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?