# Dropwizard REST API server exited with code 1

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am facing a weird issue. My REST API server started successfully initially but within a second it shows an error: `rest_web_1 exited with code 1`

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2017-08-02T17:10:17.046289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-08-02T17:32:02.558126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-08-02T17:32:08.592558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar db migrate config.yml && java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.server.connector.port=25407 -jar target/rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml`
2017-08-02T17:32:11.191891+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-08-02T17:32:11.196719+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-08-02T17:32:14.934624+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:14,927] com.xxx.restapi.RESTAPIConfiguration: Dropwizard db url: unused-url
2017-08-02T17:32:14.946383+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:14,945] com.xxx.restapi.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration: create db for url postgres://zbmzcwisbahqdv:acbd315fe0cfef2f09f863bd917943ac65c07c91426c250e5be73f1c36c78067@ec2-107-22-173-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d501u91mttif5a
2017-08-02T17:32:14.955800+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:14,955] com.xxx.restapi.RESTAPIConfiguration: Heroku database URL = jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-173-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d501u91mttif5a?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
2017-08-02T17:32:17.728489+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:17,727] liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
2017-08-02T17:32:22.267138+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:22,266] liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog
2017-08-02T17:32:22.519081+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:22,518] liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
2017-08-02T17:32:22.653060+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-08-02T17:32:28.741222+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:28,737] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @6083ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2017-08-02T17:32:28.870054+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:28,869] io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
2017-08-02T17:32:28.892861+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:28,892] com.xxx.restapi.RESTAPIConfiguration: Dropwizard db url: unused-url
2017-08-02T17:32:28.891933+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:28,891] io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /admin
2017-08-02T17:32:28.894018+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:28,893] com.xxx.restapi.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration: create db for url postgres://zbmzcwisbahqdv:acbd315fe0cfef2f09f863bd917943ac65c07c91426c250e5be73f1c36c78067@ec2-107-22-173-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d501u91mttif5a
2017-08-02T17:32:28.894901+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:28,894] com.xxx.restapi.RESTAPIConfiguration: Heroku database URL = jdbc:postgresql://ec2-107-22-173-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d501u91mttif5a?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
2017-08-02T17:32:29.556538+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:29,556] org.hibernate.Version: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {0.0.1-SNAPSHOT}
2017-08-02T17:32:29.580604+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:29,579] io.dropwizard.hibernate.SessionFactoryFactory: Entity classes: [com.xxx.restapi.model.REST, com.xxx.restapi.model.HardwareVersion]
2017-08-02T17:32:29.558231+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:29,557] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-08-02T17:32:29.674259+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:29,673] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-08-02T17:32:31.480300+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:31,479] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
2017-08-02T17:32:32.988141+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:32,987] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-08-02T17:32:32.991166+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:32,990] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@b3e86d5
2017-08-02T17:32:34.138436+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,134] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.Currency] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@9b47400
2017-08-02T17:32:34.139054+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,138] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.Duration] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.DurationType@747835f5
2017-08-02T17:32:34.139441+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,139] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.Instant] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.InstantType@51d0ec6f
2017-08-02T17:32:34.140427+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,139] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.LocalDate] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.LocalDateType@4e0cc334
2017-08-02T17:32:34.140757+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,140] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.LocalDateTime] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType@1e12a5a6
2017-08-02T17:32:34.141057+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,140] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.LocalTime] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.LocalTimeType@47a7c93e
2017-08-02T17:32:34.141482+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,141] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.OffsetDateTime] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.OffsetDateTimeType@6f9ab79d
2017-08-02T17:32:34.142354+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,142] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.OffsetTime] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.OffsetTimeType@64ae105d
2017-08-02T17:32:34.147946+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,145] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry: HHH000270: Type registration [java.time.ZonedDateTime] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.ZonedDateTimeType@10a18e3e
2017-08-02T17:32:34.778461+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,769] com.xxx.restapi.RESTAPIApplication: Starting REST-API app server
2017-08-02T17:32:34.801376+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,801] io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
2017-08-02T17:32:34.812575+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,810] io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /admin
2017-08-02T17:32:34.822918+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:34,814] io.dropwizard.server.ServerFactory: Starting rest-api
2017-08-02T17:32:35.950162+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-02T17:32:35.870712+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:35,867] org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Opened rest-api@69a5c6be{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:25407}
2017-08-02T17:32:35.870854+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:35,869] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-08-02T17:32:36.159048+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-08-02 17:32:36,158] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started rest-api@69a5c6be{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:25407}
2017-08-02T17:32:36.159396+00:00 app[web.1]: org/glassfish/jersey/spi/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutorProvider
2017-08-02T17:32:36.765005+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-08-02T17:32:36.778743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

**Updated:**

```
Dockerfile
FROM heroku/java
```

```
docker-compose.yml
web:
  build: .
  command: 'bash -c ''java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar db migrate config.yml && java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.server.connector.port=$PORT -jar target/rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml'''
  working_dir: /app/user
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@herokuPostgresql:5432/postgres'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
shell:
  build: .
  command: bash
  working_dir: /app/user
  environment:
    PORT: 8080
    DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://postgres:@herokuPostgresql:5432/postgres'
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
  links:
    - herokuPostgresql
  volumes:
    - '.:/app/user'
herokuPostgresql:
  image: postgres
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what's going wrong here?

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Updated question, I think it's not docker issue because showing same error in Heroku logs.

Comment: Yes, I also think you can rule out docker. The stack trace that you get is the relevant part to solve the problem. Here is a question with the same error (maybe it is even a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637330/unable-to-build-hibernate-sessionfactory  Unfortunately, it does not have an answer, so it will not help you. :-(

Comment: I removed the Docker tags, but more importantly, I added the Java tag. I think the best target audience for that problem is the Java community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a fix for the issue. I think it was due to `jersey-media-multipart` dependency, as and when I removed it, it starts working fine. Might be dependency version specific.